# create list of bucket indexes based on length of pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I have a pandas dataframe with say 100 rows. I want to create a list of indexes based on N value.

For example:

If N value is given as 10, then I want to create 10 bucket list somewhat like below:

```
list = [(0,10), (10, 20), (20, 30)........(90, 100)]

If N =2

list = [(0,50), (50, 100)]
```

if I have say 98 rows and N=10, my list should look like

```
[(0, 10), (10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40), (40, 50), (50, 60), (60, 70), (70, 80), (80, 90), (90, 98)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script

```
rows = 98
n = 10
rows_rounded = rows + n - (rows % n) if rows % n != 0 else rows
out = [(x, x + int(rows_rounded/n)) for x in range(0, rows_rounded, int(rows_rounded/n))]
out[:-1] + [(rows_rounded - int(rows_rounded/n), rows)]
```

Output

```
[(0, 10), (10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40), (40, 50), (50, 60), (60, 70), (70, 80), (80, 90), (90, 98)]
```

Comment: if I have 98 rows, my list should look like  [(0, 10), (10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40), (40, 50), (50, 60), (60, 70), (70, 80), (80, 90), (90, 98)]

Comment: You can use mod instead of division.

Comment: Actually wait one moment.